# Visual C++ throws map exception because of comperator

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I have a C++ code that is running on Linux but I get a bug in Visual C++ on Windows. The code is the following:

```
struct dependence {
    dependence() {}
    dependence(string CUid, LID sink, LID source, std::string var)
    : CUid(CUid), sink(sink), source(source), var(var) {}

    string CUid;

    LID sink = 0;
    LID source = 0;
    std::string var;
};

struct dependenceCompare {
    bool operator() (const dependence& lhs, const dependence& rhs) const{
    return ((lhs.CUid<rhs.CUid) || (lhs.source<rhs.source) || (lhs.sink < rhs.sink) || (lhs.var < rhs.var));

    }
};
```

When running the code on Windows I get the following error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!" c:\windows\system32\MSCP120D.dll c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree line 1795 Expression: invalid operator<
>   When I change the comparator to just one if clause, it works:

```
struct dependenceCompare {
    bool operator() (const dependence& lhs, const dependence& rhs) const{
        return ((lhs.CUid < rhs.CUid));
    }
};
```

I have read this thread, but could not find out where the problem is and why it is working in Linux with **cmake** but not in Visual Studio C++.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the *non-working* code. Including how you use the structures you show us.

Comment: What if you press _ignore_ on said debug assertion? Debug assertions, are not, _technically_, errors, and are visible, well, only in debug builds.

Comment: This is a debug assertion, not an exception. And it comes with interesting instructions. You need to get into the habit of actually reading error/warning dialogs.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius putting your fingers in your ears is not a good way of debugging code.

Comment: @Sneftel Where did I tell, that it was? I said, that, _technically_ it wasn't an error, and, in the end, it should work, exactly as it does on linux. It just so happens, that MSVC does a little bit more checks, and informs you, that you may have made a mistake, but it doesn't make the assertion itself, an error, that's stopping your program from running, or an exception, that does the same.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No, it shouldn't work. Using a comparison which does not fill the requirements of `Compare` leads to undefined behavior, and will definitely produce incorrect results on *any* platform. That's what the message is trying to say. Ignoring it is a bad idea.

Comment: @Sneftel Are you even reading what I type? Because, currently, it doesn't seem like you do. I didn't state that _it would work_. I stated _it should work, exactly as it does on linux_, i.e. there shouldn't be any difference between the 2 implementations.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No, it's perfectly reasonable and expected for there to be differences. Again, this is *undefined behavior*. It's acceptable for a given standard library implementation to respond by working improperly, by throwing up an assertion, or just by crashing, regardless of what any other implementation does.

Comment: @Sneftel 1) that's why I said _should_, instead of _will_. 2) If it is undefined behavior, please, specify a section of C++ standard, that says so, because I failed to find it (and clearly, you know better).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The requirements of Compare are given in [alg.sorting], and the consequences of violating them are given in [res.on.functions].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like `a.i < b.i || a.j < b.j` is not a "strict weak ordering" as required by things like `std::map`, because it means that given two items, each one can be less than the other.

It's common to see multi-field comparisons of this form:

```
if(a.i != b.i) return a.i < b.i;
if(a.j != b.j) return a.j < b.j;
return a.k < b.k;
```

That's probably more like what you want: Giving precedence to one field, but using another field to break ties.

You can simplify that code by using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
return (std::tie(a.i, a.j, a.k) < std::tie(b.i, b.j, b.k));
```

For your code, it will be:

```
return ( std::tie(lhs.CUid, lhs.source, lhs.sink, lhs.var)
         < std::tie(rhs.CUid, rhs.source, rhs.sink, rhs.var));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know why this bug is catched in VS but not in linux?

Comment: @MoProg Because different standard library implementations have gone to different amounts of trouble to check for bugs like this. Be assured, your code was incorrect on all platforms, and would have caused subtler problems on those that didn't warn you up-front.